# I2S output to a sound card

Tags: audio, mems, i2s, mems-microphone

I followed [this tutorial on building a microphone](http://www.instructables.com/id/Coco-Mic-The-DIY-Studio-Quailty-USB-Mic-MEMS-techn/?ALLSTEPS) with two MEMS mics and a cheap USB sound card - it works pretty well, although I'm looking to upgrade the MEMS mics to some with better SNR and sensitivity.

I was looking at [these microphones](http://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/ICS-43432_DS.pdf). They output i2s data, whereas the MEMS mics in the tutorial output an analog signal (edit - not PDM data).

If I use one of the same cheap USB sound cards, is that capable of receiving i2s data in the same way as they are receiving PDM? I understand that these i2s mics expect to output sound to a "DSP, microcontroller, or codec" - I'm just not sure if the sound card is considered one of those.

I also am aware that i2s MEMS mics have pins for "word select" and clock -- are those connections required for an i2s microphone to output a signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MEMs mics used in the tutorial don't output data, they put out a plain old analog audio signal that is digitized by the USB Soundcard.

The ones you are looking at (the ones whose datasheet you linked to) are designed for digital interfaces and CANNOT be used in place of the analog ones.